# play Framework Tomcat new File failure

Tags: java, json, tomcat, playframework, playframework-2.0

Following problem. I want to deploy my play Framework webapp as a war file on a Tomcat. The deployment works, but it can't create a new (json) file. Here is the code:

```
try {
        input.setId(id); 
        mapper.writeValue(new File(id + ".json"), input);
        return redirect(routes.Application.output(id));

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        String fail = "FAIL :(";
        return ok(index.render(fail));
    }
```

In this piece of code the IOException is thrown whenever i use it. FYI the mapper comes from the Jackson plugin. The webapp works in dev mode on my PC, but not with Tomcat on the server. My play Framework version is 2.3.5 and my Tomcat version is 6.

Is there any possibility to create new files with a play Framework webapp and Tomcat?

Comment: stacktrace? did you find out why exactly is it failing? Could be a genuine IO error or a file permission issue for all that we know.

Comment: Ok next problem. How can I enable logging?